# how to get minimum index number in arraylist java?

Tags: java

i m using this code for getting index number but i can't get minimum index number

```
    for(String it : list1){
        index = list.indexOf(it);
        System.out.println("\n index1 : " +it);        
    }

    for(String it1 : list1){
        index1 = list.indexOf(it1);
        System.out.println("\nindex2 : " +it1);        
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a regular for loop with index instead?

Comment: question not clear....can u explain more?

Comment: Can you add more details? the purpose/objective and etc. what is item1? is is supposed to it1? or is it a variable declared outside?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
int min =Math.min(index ,index1 )
```

For more information about the min function see the official [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

This looks much simple

```
for (int index = 0; index<list1.size(); index++) {
    System.out.println("index of item is: " + index);
}
```

Comment: does not answer the quest. OP askes which is the index of the first occurrence of the item, because it might be contained more than once in the list

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep it in another variable on the side:

```
String minStr;
int minIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(String it : list1)
{
    index = list.indexOf(item);
    if (index < minIndex) {
        minIndex = index;
        minStr = it;
    }
}
System.out.println ("The minimal index is " + minIndex + "( + minStr + ")");
```

Comment: this is redundant, see the javadoc for `List.indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) `List.indexOf(obj)` returns the **minimum** index if the element is present in the list, or -1 otherwise. So basically you don't have to do anything besides calling `indexOf`